# How to get second attribute level with Selenium's xpath

Tags: xpath, selenium, selenium-rc

I'm trying to check in Selenium if an element has a green border or not.

i can use `//div[@id="target"]/@style` to get the parsed style string applied... and use string search to search for the border... i have to work around some brosers showing the shorthand (`border: solid 3px green`) and other showing the expanded (`border-style: solid; border-color: green....`) ...but how could i do that more cleanly?

ideally something like: `//div[@id="target"]/@style.borderColor`

I also would like to avoid using the `contains` selector because the syntax is awful. But if it's the only way, so be it. of course.

Comment: I'm kind of baffled. Are you implying that you can get the `style` value via XPath using `//div[@id="target"]/@style` in Selenium? How? Or are you just testing whether it returns an element or not?

Comment: yes, in selenium. just use getAttribute() @Slanec

Comment: Oh, right, Selenium RC. It looked like a proper XPath :). And the `style` attribute is explicitly typed on the `div` element, or is it just a `<div class="greenBox">` with CSS defined? Or, in another words, do you want to get the computed border volor value, or the explicit value in the `style` attribute?

Comment: @Slanec ouch, i thought i mentioned selenium on the title... will fix it. I want the computed value.

Comment: You mentioned Selenium, not Selenium RC. There's Selenium WebDriver, too, you know. And RC has been deprecated for over a year. Now that I know what's going on...

Comment: very good link when using xpaths http://test-able.blogspot.ie/2016/04/xpath-selectors-cheat-sheet.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XPath doesn't know anything about CSS styles, it doesn't understand the attributes and takes them just as simple strings. It would be weird if a XML query language understood CSS styles, right?

Besides, the [`getAttribute()`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/Selenium.html#getAttribute%28java.lang.String%29) uses a construct *similar* to XPath, but *not* XPath! It also selects the attribute via `@` sign, right. But consider this locator: `"id=target@style"`. It would work, but it's definitely no XPath.

It would also return the explicitly set `style` attribute, not it's internal computed value, so it's useless unless there actually is a `style` attribute on the element. If there is `style` attribute defined, go for it.

Selenium itself can't give you the right answer (WebDriver has [`getCssValue()`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getCssValue%28java.lang.String%29), but there's no counterpart for it in Selenium RC, afaik).

Therefore, the only way to get the computed style (the final value computed from all sources) of an element in Selenium RC is via JavaScript.

The script that has been working for me for ages (after a slight edit) is this (from [quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/getstyles.html#link7)):

```
function getStyle(id, stylePropJs, stylePropCss) {
    var x = document.getElementById(id);
    if (x.currentStyle)
        var y = x.currentStyle[stylePropJs];
    else if (window.getComputedStyle)
        var y = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(x,null).getPropertyValue(stylePropCss);
    return y;
}
```

Note that IE needs a JavaScript name of the property, but every other browser uses CSS names. Also, you *can't* use the shorthand property and you definitely *must* use the expanded one. Therefore, in your case:

```
String script = "var x = document.getElementById('target');" +
                "if (x.currentStyle) var y = x.currentStyle['borderTopColor'];" +
                "else if (window.getComputedStyle) var y = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(x,null).getPropertyValue('border-top-color');" +
                "y;";
String color = selenium.getEval(script);
```

This returns the color of the top border (yep, you'll need to call it four times in order to get the whole border) of the `target` element. But guess what! Every browser returns the color in a different format. Fortunately, at least in Java, there's a [`Color`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/Color.html) class that can easily reformat it:

```
String color = Color.fromString(color).asHex();
```

Now that you have a hex encoded color stored, you can trivially make check whether it's green or not.